# $_SESSION doesn't take data over different pages

Tags: php, session

For some reason I don't manage to take some date from one page to another using the `$_SESSION`-variable.

On my `index.php`-page is a form where users can login.
I start with (where `session_start()` is in the `inc_admin.php`-file):

```
require_once '../includes/php/inc_admin.php';

if ($_GET['page'] == 'login') {
    $action = loginUser($_DB, $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['password']);
}

if(isset($_SESSION["user"])) {
    $action .= header('Location: ../admin/index.php');
}

echo $action;
```

The `loginUser`-function does set (among other) the `$_SESSION`:

```
$user = Leaders::getLogin($_DB, $firstname, $password);
if(!empty($user)) {
    $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
}
```

And as t should, when the user submits the form with correct data, he will be redirected to the `../admin/index.php`-page. However, if I take a `var_dump($_SESSION)`, the page tells me this variable is `NULL`.

What more do I need to do to make sure data is transferred over pages using `$_SESSION`?

Comment: does the /admin/index.php page also include    session_start()?

Comment: Nope, it didn't. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you call session_start() somewhere everytime you reload a page, or else the server won't get the session details.

Answer (score 2):

Each page needs to begin with

```
session_start();
```

it resumes the previously created session

Answer (score 0):

Call "**session_start()**;" before any output on the page (even before any Header() is sent). Best is to place it at the very top of the page.